# notepad++: How to return to previous position? without mark than position previously

Tags: notepad++

If I am editing a large document in **notepad++**,

Then, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> and the curso goes to the end of the file.

**Is there any method to position the cursor in the previous position?**

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: see [Keyboard And Mouse Shortcuts](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Keyboard_And_Mouse_Shortcuts)

Comment: Thanks. May be there is another way. I change shortcut to methos. May be it is posible to program a macro or a pluggin.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is the plugin "location navigate".

https://sourceforge.net/projects/locationnav/

Features

Automatic record the cursor position, you can set each position offset.

You can jump to any position that your cursor have been visited.

Can use shortcut( ctrl + - for back position and ctrl + shift+ - for forward position ) to jump code back and forward

History position can automatic adjusted when text modify.

Support jump between open files, if files closed ,it will open it automatic.

Location history can be set to whether cleaned when file is closed

Can jump to any modified location ( ctrl+atl + z ) back and forward ( ctrl+atl + y ) in the history list it is marked by '!'

Will always record the position even after you jumped by setting 'Always record'.

Toolbar's button will auto be diabled or enabled in different state

Comment: I test it. It is a very good plugin

Comment: Also, if you like, you can change the keyboard shortcut commands for this plugin in the Notepad++ keyboard settings. I set them to Alt-Left and Alt+Right Arrow.

Comment: A word of caution - Its a wonderful plugin, but I've noticed it **crash** `Notepad++` sometimes, specially in auto recording mode. I'd lost unsaved changes multiple times because of this. The crash maybe specific to my machine, but still wanted users to be vigilant.

Comment: Awsome! The hot key is the same as visual stuido which I used to. Thanks.

Comment: Update to my earlier comment: I recently found bug reported on official npp tracker. Other users have also reported similar behavior when using this plugin. From high level the plugin may not be entirely responsible, but as part of its operation, it does things that causes Notepad++ to crash. [Source](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/240).

Comment: "Location Navigate" is an "Available" plugin in NotePad++ (at least in 8.5.7.0), so **you do not need to download it**.
 
**Instead**, go to `Plugins` -> `Plugin Admin…` -> `Available` -> `Search` for "Location Navigate" -> `Install`.

Answer (score 2):

For navigating back to the previous position I do CTRL-Z then CTRL-Y. That's the easiest and quickest method. When it undoes the previous text change and puts it back the cursor stays at the last change. If you have a large document enter a comment such as "mark here" and search for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

I use the [SourceCookifier](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecookifier/) plugin, which can be installed from **Plugins**  ► **Plugin Admin**.

Among its other functionality, it navigates back and forth with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd>.

> Features:
>
> - Go to definition
> - Navigate backward/forward
> - Tag name search
> - Different session modes
> - Customizable appearance and parsing rules
> - Supports custom languages

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]